# Как правильно настроить ndk уже в существующем проекте?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Есть проект, я хочу использовать ndk.
Я установил в `SDK Tools`:

```
- NDK  
- CMake
```

Дальше последовал:

```
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code#create-sources
```

Но у меня не получается запустить проект.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно внедрить `ndk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ, может кому пригодится. 
В gradle добавляете:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
            ....
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags ""
                }
            }
        }  


    externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
}
```